# 9 patch image prevent build project android studio

Tags: android, build, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am moving to Gradle build . but i have this error for a lot of 9-patch images .

Note the drawable is auto generated by `http://android-holo-colors.com`
but they are old.

I am using android studio `0.5.1` 
and my build tool version is `19.0.3`
this is the error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt s -i /Users/Ed/Desktop/TestAndroid/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/spinner_default_holo_dark.9.png -o /Users/Ed/Desktop/TestAndroid/app/build/res/all/debug/drawable-mdpi/spinner_default_holo_dark.9.png
  Error Code:
    42
  Output:
    ERROR: 9-patch image /Users/Ed/Desktop/TestAndroid/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/spinner_default_holo_dark.9.png malformed.
           Frame pixels must be either solid or transparent (not intermediate alphas).
           Found at pixel #3 along top edge.
    /Users/Ed/Desktop/TestAndroid/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/cab_background_bottom_test.9.png
    Error:Ticks in transparent frame must be black or red. - ERROR: 9-patch image /Users/Ed/Desktop/TestAndroid/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/spinner_default_holo_dark.9.png malformed.
```

Anyone faced the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried following the suggestions in the error log?
I.e. take a look at the 3rd (possibly 4th if it treats it as zero indexed?) Pixel along the top row in an image editor:

- Is the pixel red or black (#FF0000 or #000000)?
- Does it have an alpha value of 255 or 0?

If the answer is "no", then I guess that's your problem. This will then obviously also need to be applied to all other marker pixels around the edge of the images.

I'd add this as a comment, but don't have enough rep - sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I saw a solution in other feed and the way to fix this issue is to use draw9patch tool to open the image and save it directly. I use this way to solve this issue.
About "draw9patch", you can use that tool in the tools directory of the Android sdk folder or use it directly by clicking the image within the Android Studio, it uses draw9patch as well.

Comment: Great. I'd like to add that the tool is simply accessed by double-clicking the image in the project tree. Then define the 9 tiles by dragging the borders and save.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents,

I used photoshop to create my ninepatch and came across this error.

I had used the brush tool in brush mode with the black color to paint the border pixels (content and stretch)

The problem with the brush is that it also colors contiguous pixels with just a tiny amount of very transparent black so that you can't see it. Using the eraser in 1px crayon mode on all the pixel that should have been transparent worked for me.

When working on a nine patch in photoshop always use the brush tool in crayon mode