# Error at a compile time with 9.png

Tags: android, image, nine-patch

I have two 9.png images created with the generator [Nine Patches](https://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html). When I run the app Android Studio stops and say me that the images have an error on the pixel #394. What is the problem??

These are the images.

[image: Purple]
[image: Green]

The error in the log:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\aapt.exe s -i D:\Users\McFly\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncro\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\spinner_line.9.png -o D:\Users\McFly\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncro\app\build\res\all\debug\drawable-xxhdpi\spinner_line.9.png
Error Code:
    42
Output:
    ERROR: 9-patch image D:\Users\McFly\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncro\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\spinner_line.9.png malformed.
           Frame pixels must be either solid or transparent (not intermediate alphas).
           Found at pixel #364 along top edge.
```

Comment: Could you post the whole error message?

Comment: Also what version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: As far as I know, you can set content that should not be streched on the top and right side. left and bottom are for padding. both of your images are crossing those patches. But the whole error message would be helpful.

Comment: I used Android Studio 0.5.5

Comment: `pixels must be either solid or transparent (not intermediate alphas)`

Comment: As I had said, I made the images with the web tool of nine patch

Comment: I did my images with GIMP and added the 9-patch with the draw9patch.bat from the sdk. And it worked out immediatly.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280398/9-patch-image-error-in-android

Comment: And see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309169/9-patch-image-prevent-build-project-android-studio

Answer (score -1):

Rename the file to example.png rather than example.9.png. I had same issue in past and renaming helped me.

Comment: The whole point is the png to be 9 patch. Removing the extension does not answer this question.

Comment: @pratz9999 is sugesting to remove the patch number, not the extension. Actually, this advice did help me.