# Android Error Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: android

I am having trouble with getting rid of the error Cannot resolve symbol 'R'. I have done some research but none has worked. Among the tips i have tried out include **Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle Files** after which I executed the **Build->Clean Project**. The clean project command resulted with the following error;

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Crunching Cruncher abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png failed

My xml files have the following error:

> NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views.  Fix compilation problems first
>
> Exception raised during rendering: action_bar

What might I be missing? I will appreciate any help or pointers.

Comment: are there any error in xml

Comment: Go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29992257/2276657)

Comment: Most common problem in android

Comment: post your xml code which contains custom view

Comment: Thanks @Udit, got a helpful tip from your link.

Comment: @Shakeeb, it's all good. Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments above, @Udit posted a link to another sort of related question from which I was able to get a solution. Incase you run into a similar problem, the solution is quite simple.  Reboot Android Studio and then go to **Build->Rebuild Project**. Hope this will sort out your issue as it did mine. Thank you all for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Crunching
>   Cruncher abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png failed

--->Is this error message from the gradle console?

Because this happened to me once when the PNG file I used wasn't a "pure" PNG file. Like for example: An image I found from the internet that wasn't really a PNG file(ex: jpg/Gif image) but I just renamed it to to a ".PNG" file upon saving it then directly copied this to res/drawable. So to fix this I deleted the image and used a real PNG file by either editing it on Photoshop or a real png file from the internet or whatever and then did @Biko's advice which was to **Reboot Android Studio and then go to Build->Rebuild Project.**