# Eclipse to Android Studio importing error

Tags: android, android-studio, importerror, libpng

While importing a project I got the following error :

```
 AAPT err(Facade for 3882930): libpng error: Read Error

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ProjectName:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I tried to clean, rebuild and also restart studio as well as my PC but no luck. Can anyone help me?

Comment: post full logcat @Parth Anjaria

Comment: this might help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026024/errorexecution-failed-for-task-projectnamemergedebugresources-crunching

Comment: @AmitVaghela this is the full relevant log

Comment: @YogeshPatel i tried to clean the project. and i am already using 1.5 gradle to build. so the site wasnt helpful, Thankyou

Comment: ok. try doing this: goto->file >> invalidate caches/restart

Comment: Read the question above I have already tried clean,rebuild, restart studio, restart my PC. Anyother solution?

Comment: can u just check your directories of the project, if some unused files are present, try to delete them. Possibly there should be something inside your res folder that is unused. I faced it during an occurence of a 9 patch image .

Comment: Ohk ill check that and let you know, thank you anyways

Comment: sorry @YogeshPatel this did not work

Comment: just try to create a new project and then copy all the classes and the required folders from eclipse to the required android studio project instead of importing it..

Comment: Yes, I am trying that only

Comment: Thank you @YogeshPatel for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got an answer,

I took all the images an pasted them on https://tinypng.com/ and downloaded the optimized images. put them in their respective  positions and Voila the error was gone.

I guess the images had corrupted as it was a 1 year old project which i was trying to import.

Comment: I guessed a bit correctly, it was indeed a problem from your res files...glad u solved it...