# Failed to crunch some files Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, aapt

Recently I migrated an eclipse project to Android Studio and I am now getting following error when building project

> AAPT err(Facade for 170558904): libpng error: Not a PNG file
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>    Some
>   file crunching failed, see logs for details

By following various questions related to this, I renamed all .9.png to .png. It is not even showing filename which is showing error. How can I figure out which file is having that issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026024/errorexecution-failed-for-task-projectnamemergedebugresources-crunching

Comment: earlier they were .9.png but I read that making them .png can work

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have read your answer and other related post already and tried everything from that but it is not working. Earlier it was showing that the following file has some problem but now it doesn't even show which file is having error

Comment: Yeah .I got notification.Whats your gradle version  ?? any alpha version ?

Comment: yes 2.0 beta version

Comment: i mean `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'` ??

Comment: yes `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6`

Comment: i guess `beta6` buggy . Is there any problem with `beta5` or `beta2` ?

Comment: I only tried with beta6 now trying with 1.5

Comment: with 1.5 I am getting this warning for files other than .9.png
`AAPT err(Facade for 247064166): C:\svn\ficcistudiocode-template\codebtrunk\Cebit_ficci2\SmartCrm\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\bubble_shadow.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495147/android-studio-libpng-warning-iccp-not-recognizing-known-srgb-profile-that-h

Comment: thats mean problem for `bubble_shadow`

Comment: bubble_shadow was a .9.png before but I converted it to png

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya can we convert 9png to normal png properly either online or using some tool?

Comment: As far as i know ,There is no for this .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I was trying and able to remove one error.Now it doesn't show not a PNG file error but I still have some crunching failed error. How I can see the logs which that error says

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution failed for task 'app:mergeDebugResources' Crunching Cruncher....png failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is changue la buildDir in build.gradle:

working for me.

For example:

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Rebuild and happy coding.

Comment: my problem was not due to project path. It was due to bad png files.