# Android Studio : Error:Execution failed for task ':***:mergeDebugResources'. > Some file crunching failed

Tags: android, android-studio, resources

I have already applied possible solution given on SO ,but no luck .
Just transform my existing eclispe project in to studio and stuck at this point .

getting this error :

> **Error:Execution failed for task ':xxx:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed**

and this warning too,

> **libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited**

Below are the solutions I already tried ,

1>[Some file crunching failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026024/errorexecution-failed-for-task-projectnamemergedebugresources-crunching)

> 2>  check out all image names for their proper extension
>
> 3> clean and rebuild the project so many times :/

Here is **build.gradle** file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':main1')
    compile project(':main')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/analytics-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/classes.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/pinchzoom.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.6.1-with-src.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```

and this is **class path** :

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'


    }
}
```

can any one please figure out where I'm wrong !!, any suggestion will acceptable.
Thanks in advance .